# Name attribute on hidden <input> not updating with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drupal-7

I have a dynamically built form for building a carousel in Drupal with pre-defined inputs which should get updated when clicking an "Add Slide" button.  When clicking the button the form does update, but due to the way Drupal builds forms with managed file uploads, there are two  elements that need to be changed for every managed file upload field.  The first element gets updated, but the second will not get updated.  The reason this needs to be updated is so that when the form submits, it gets the values for all of the slides.  The name attribute of the hidden input that won't update is: *image_file[fid]*.

Javascript on the page:

```
var c = 0;
(function ($) {
  var nid;
  Drupal.carousel_npd_data_form = Drupal.carousel_npd_data_form || {};
  Drupal.behaviors.carousel_npd_data_form = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var nid = Drupal.settings.carousel_npd_data_form.nid;
      var field_name = Drupal.settings.carousel_npd_data_form.field_name;
      var form_location = 'carousel/form';
      var node_carousel_form_location = 'carousel/form/' + nid + '/' + field_name;

      init();

      /**
       * Run some stuff before stuff happens.
       */
      function init() {
        var nodeResponse = retrieveNodeCarousel();
        var carousel_data = nodeResponse.response;
        if (carousel_data == '{carousel:[]}' || " " || "") {
          // carousel data for node is empty
        } else {
          // carousel data for node exists
        }
      }

      /**
       * Returns the carousel JSON data for a node.
       * @return {[JSON]} node carousel value
       */
      function retrieveNodeCarousel() {
        return $.ajax({
          async: false,
          type: "POST",
          url: Drupal.settings.basePath + node_carousel_form_location,
        });
      }

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Javascript for the button click (this temporarily lives on the form itself rather than in a js file):

```
        event.preventDefault();
        var sheep = (jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c);
        c++
        var klone = (jQuery)(sheep).clone().attr(\'id\', \'carousel-editor-slide-\'+c);
        console.log(klone);
        (jQuery)(klone).insertAfter(sheep);
        (jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c+\' :input\').each(function(i, obj){
          console.log(obj);
          var field_id = (jQuery)(obj).attr(\'id\');
          if (field_id.length > 0) {
            var new_id = field_id+\'-\'+c;
            (jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c).find(\'#\'+field_id).attr(\'id\', new_id);
          }
          var field_name = (jQuery)(obj).attr(\'name\');
          var new_name = field_name+\'_\'+c;
          console.log(new_name);
          (jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c+\' :input[name^=\'+field_name+\']\').attr(\'name\', new_name);
          console.log((jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c+\' :input[name^=\'+new_name+\']\'));
        });
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="carousel-editor"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Carousel</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="fieldset-description">Add information to the carousel here.</div><fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="carousel-editor-slide-0"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Slide</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-carousel-image-title">
  <label for="edit-image-title">Image Title </label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-image-title" name="carousel_image_title" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
<div id="edit-image-file-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-carousel-image-file">
  <label for="edit-image-file">Upload an Image </label>
 <div id="edit-image-file" class="form-managed-file"><input type="file" id="edit-image-file-upload" name="files[image_file]" size="22" class="form-file"><input type="hidden" name="image_file[fid]" value="0">
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-video-embed">
  <label for="edit-video-embed">Video Embed </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-video-embed" name="carousel_video_embed" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-text">
  <label for="edit-text">Text </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-text" name="carousel_text" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
</div></fieldset>
</div></fieldset>
```

After clicking the button, the HTML looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="carousel-editor"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Carousel</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="fieldset-description">Add information to the carousel here.</div><fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="carousel-editor-slide-0"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Slide</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-carousel-image-title">
  <label for="edit-image-title">Image Title </label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-image-title" name="carousel_image_title" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
<div id="edit-image-file-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-carousel-image-file">
  <label for="edit-image-file">Upload an Image </label>
 <div id="edit-image-file" class="form-managed-file"><input type="file" id="edit-image-file-upload" name="files[image_file]" size="22" class="form-file"><input type="hidden" name="image_file[fid]" value="0">
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-video-embed">
  <label for="edit-video-embed">Video Embed </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-video-embed" name="carousel_video_embed" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-text">
  <label for="edit-text">Text </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-text" name="carousel_text" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
</div></fieldset><fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="carousel-editor-slide-1"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Slide</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-carousel-image-title">
  <label for="edit-image-title">Image Title </label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-image-title-1" name="carousel_image_title_1" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
<div id="edit-image-file-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-carousel-image-file">
  <label for="edit-image-file">Upload an Image </label>
 <div id="edit-image-file" class="form-managed-file"><input type="file" id="edit-image-file-upload-1" name="files[image_file]" size="22" class="form-file"><input type="hidden" name="image_file[fid]" value="0">
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-video-embed">
  <label for="edit-video-embed">Video Embed </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-video-embed-1" name="carousel_video_embed_1" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-carousel-text">
  <label for="edit-text">Text </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-text-1" name="carousel_text_1" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
</div></fieldset>
</div></fieldset>
```

All of the other inputs get their names and/or IDs updated, so I'm not sure why the hidden element is not getting updated.

EDIT: I just realized there is another  tag with ID that is being duplicated as well, but the ID is not being told to update.  While I don't think that's what's causing the issue of the hidden 's attribute to not be updated it is something I will address.

Comment: typo ? `onclick="avascript:`

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue This is anyway still valid ;)

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue - Type while making the question rather than in the code, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is bunch of unreadable code you have there. You should really avoid inline scripting

Comment: @A.Wolff - I'll try to format better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working was because of this line in the JS:

```
(jQuery)(\'#carousel-editor-slide-\'+c+\' :input[name^=\'+field_name+\']\').attr(\'name\', new_name);
```

Since this was both inline JS and embeded in PHP it was difficult to fix the issue.  I ended up doing it all in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CR47/hpfmbnfz/1/).  From there I found a way to move my code out of PHP all together, which was in it of itself [a difficult problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145868/having-trouble-selecting-elements-in-jquery-with-js-added-on-the-form?noredirect=1).

The working line of code is this:

```
$('#carousel-editor-slide-'+c).find('input[name^=\''+field_name+'\']').attr('name', new_name);
```

The main fix here being that the field_name variable is now wrapped in its own escaped quotes.